# ERROR [22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: vb.net

I have an error **ERROR [22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.** and I've been trying to solve this but unfortunately I couldn't get the hack of this error. I'm a newbie in dotNet.

```
Public Sub LogInContinue(ByVal senter As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim LibDS As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim LibDA As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblUserAccount WHERE Uname='" & txtUserName.Text & "'", LibConn)
    Dim A As Integer
    LibDS.Tables.Add("tblUserAccount")
    A = LibDA.Fill(LibDS, "tblUserAccount")

    If A = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Username you have supplied is invalid!" & vbCrLf & "Please click OK button to try again.", "INVALID USERNAME", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        If LibDS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Uname") = Me.txtUserName.Text AndAlso LibDS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Password") = Me.txtPassword.Text Then
            NewUserID.UUserID = LibDS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("UserID")
            UserAcceptedRole()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Password you have supplied is invalid." & vbCrLf & "Please try again!", "PASSWORD MISMATCHED", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserAcceptedRole()
    Dim ActualRole As String
    Dim LibDSa As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim LibDAa As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblRoles WHERE UserID='" & NewUserID.UUserID & "'", LibConn)
    LibDSa.Tables.Add("tblRoles")
    LibDAa.Fill(LibDSa, "tblRoles")

    ActualRole = LibDS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Role").ToString
    If ActualRole = "Member" Then
        lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome " & txtUserName.Text
        NewObject.NewLabel(lblID, "You are logged in as " & ActualRole, "Calibri", 12, FontStyle.Regular, 666, 40)
        btnLogIn.Text = "Logout"
    End If
End Sub
```

The error is in the code `LibDAa.Fill(LibDSa, "tblRoles")` under the `Private Sub UserAcceptedRole()`. Kindly tell me what this error is all about? and if you have some advice for the improvement of my code(style), kindly tell me. Thanks loads.

Comment: What is the field type of UserID of tblRoles? and remove the statmenet   - LibDSa.Tables.Add("tblRoles").

Comment: Now debug (or add a break point ) UserAcceptedRole() method and verify the value of **NewUserID.UUserID**. Does the value of NewUserID.UUserID is number?

Comment: @AVD I tried to change it to **Long** but there's another error. _ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The table 'tblRoles' is already opened exclusively by another user, or it is already open through the user interface and cannot be manipulated programmatically._

Comment: Close the Ms-Access application window.

Comment: @AVD The previous error has been detected again. ERROR [22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression. What datatype should I use? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use Parameters (Parameterized SQL statement). Read more on [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx) and [SQL Injection.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1568268.aspx)

```
Private Sub UserAcceptedRole()
    Dim ActualRole As String
    Dim LibDt As New DataTable
    Dim Cmd As New OdbcCommand
    Cmd.CommandText="SELECT * FROM tblRoles WHERE UserID=@UserID"
    Cmd.Connection=LibConn

    MsgBox("Verifying the value of : " & NewUserID.UUserID)

    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID",System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.Int).Value=NewUserID.UUserID

    Dim LibDAa As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(Cmd)
    LibDAa.Fill(LibDt)

    If LibDt.Rows.Count<>0 Then

      ActualRole = LibDt.Rows(0)("Role").ToString

      If ActualRole = "Member" Then
        lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome " & txtUserName.Text
        ....
      End If
    End If
End Sub
```

PS: You may use DataSet too.

Comment: **ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.** What's this error?

Comment: @aerohn - May be table or field name is misspelled. Please check the name of table and fields into Ms-Access database.

Comment: My MSAccess Database is 2003 version, created n other computer. I only have MSAccess2007 n my computer, do you think the version of the software conflicts? I could still open the database created in Access2003 n my computer.

Comment: @aerohn - Version doesn't matter here. The error - Two few parameters - will be raised when table or field name mentioned in a query is not found in database. For better understanding, write a small and concise code and test it at your end. One more suggestion that you have to use OleDB Provider instead of Odbc probider.

Answer (score 2):

The User ID may be Integer type so try to remove '' from the query that surround the user id  as '232' etc.. The error may be in the following statement:

```
Dim LibDAa As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblRoles WHERE UserID='" & NewUserID.UUserID & "'", LibConn)
```

Check this:  LibDS is local to this SUB

```
Public Sub LogInContinue(ByVal senter As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim LibDS As DataSet = New DataSet   /// local to this sub
```

How can you access this in another SUB `UserAcceptedRole()`

```
ActualRole = LibDS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Role").ToString
```

Best approach is that you pass the role as parameter.